# Making Gluten Free hot cross buns

Tags: dough, gluten-free, rising

I tried making hot cross buns over the weekend using gluten free flour. I used a standard recipe and tried substituting All purpose flour for a GF version and White bread flour for a GF version.

The recipe calls for 2 cups of each with 1/2 cup warm water and 1/2 cup warm milk and 1 1/2 tsp yeast.

However my dough just didn't rise. Can anyone give me some suggestions so as to ensure the dough rises?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gluten free flour can usually be directly substituted for regular wheat flour, but breads are a special case.  GF breads require different techniques from regular wheat bread.  Hot cross buns are a type of bread, and it seems you've tried to directly substitute the flour.

This doesn't work because a traditional bread recipe relies on gluten to give the loaf structure and hold the gasses given off by the yeast, which causes to loaf (or buns, in this case) to rise, both in the initial proving stages and in the oven.  With GF flour your dough could never have gluten, so the gasses all escaped as they were produced.

To make gluten free hot cross buns, try a recipe specifically developed for gluten free flour like [this one](https://udisglutenfree.com/recipes/hot-cross-buns/#.WsNhei7wbmE) or [this one](https://www.bobsredmill.com/recipes/how-to-make/gluten-free-hot-cross-buns/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I will certainly keep this in m ind and am keen to give the GF recipe a try.